# Find text after substring until the end of the line in python

Tags: python, string

```
String = """bob
123 -- things
stuff after that line"""
```

I need to get " things".
I have tried

```
 def InBetween(Substring1, Substring2, String):
    return String[(String.index(Substring1)+len(Substring1)):String.index(Substring2)]
Stuff = InBetween("--", "\n", String)
```

But this gives me a ValueError due to the fact that it can not get any results
any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.search`

```
>>> re.search(r'--(.*)', String).group(1)
' things'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string methods:

```
for string in text.splitlines():
    if ' -- ' in string:
        print(string.strip().split(' -- ', 1)[1])
```